# Quand utiliser "J'ai jamais" vs "Je suis jamais"?

Tags: conjugaison

When shortening phrases in natural language.
"I have never been there" or "J'y suis jamais allé".

Would a francophone say
"J'ai jamais" or would they say "Je suis jamais" instead?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question ?

Comment: @Random Do I use `ai` or `suis`? (sorry for ambiguity, Im new and still unfamiliar with customs)

Comment: Depending the sentence, you have to use one or the other. So are you only talking about "I have never been there" or do you want to know when to use "j'ai jamais" or "je suis jamais" ?

Comment: @Random Specifically `J'y suis jamais alle` which would become `Je suis jamais`. Am I correct? (forgive the lack of accents, I dont have a fancy computer)

Comment: @Alan Are you asking about the use of  *avoir* ("ai") and *être* ("suis") as auxiliary verbs or about whether or not we omit pronouns like *y* and *en* when speaking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot shorten ***J'y suis jamais allé***, which is already a short version of ***Je n'y suis jamais allé***, to ***J'ai jamais***, ***Je suis jamais***, or ***J'y suis jamais*** alone.

If you really want a very short version of it, you might simply say ***Jamais allé***.

If you want to use ***J'ai jamais***, the closest sentence would be ***J'y ai jamais été***, i.e. ***Je n'y ai jamais été*** (shortest form: ***Jamais été***) but be aware that using *être* for *aller*, despite having been constantly observed in French, can be controversial (see http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#34_strong-em-tre-pour-aller-em-strong )